# Displaying article image on full display conditionally

Tags: nodes

I would like to enable/disable visibility of article image on full display for **some** articles while keeping article image always visible on teaser display. Is there a way to achieve that apart from dealing with views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Field formatter conditions](https://drupal.org/project/ffc) module to achieve this goal.

First thing attach a field on desired content type with boolean value and then use this field value as a condition in field formatter settings to display other fields as you want.

For more information go through the module documentation.

Comment: If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.